# How to break the table elements in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I am setting up my bibliography in LaTeX. I have used `tabularx` but the problem is it tries to set the entire table all together, since the list is long, it will go over the limits of the page. Is there a way to correct this?

I have used

```
\newenvironment{eventlist}{%
\newcommand*\inskip{}
\renewcommand\item[3]{%
\inskip%
{\raggedleft\sc ##1\\[1pt]}
{##2}\\[2pt]
{\Large\it ##3}
\medskip
\renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
{\bigskip}
```

and then use

```
\begin{yearlist}

\item{2013}
{}
{bibliographic info}

\end{yearlist}
```

Comment: Did you post the wrong code fragment? Your question is about tables (longtable or supertab packages allow multi-page tables) but the code shows a definitin of `eventlist` and the use of `yearlist` none of which appear related?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you considered using BibTeX or, should you prefer to build the bibliography by hand, the `bibliography` environment and `\bibitem` commands?

Comment: Might you be looking for [`longtable`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf)? That said, there are already packages dedicated to setting bibliographies (not in a table though), so you might want to have a look at those ([`natbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) and [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) are quite popular).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - If I understand the OP's objectives, he/she is trying to build a list of bibliographic entries using a table-like or a list-type structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\usepackage{ltablex}
...
\begin{tabularx}{...}{...}
...
\end{tabularx}
```

then pagebreaks *between* tabular lines are possible. For the documentation run `texdoc ltablex.sty`